# PHPExcel - column ranges stripped from formula

Tags: php, phpexcel, formulas

I'm trying to insert a "COUNTIFS" formula and I know it's not a supported function, but I have the calculation setting turned off on the writer. It's not throwing any errors.  However,

```
$active_sheet->setCellValue('C3', "=COUNTIFS('INVENTORY'!$H:$H,1,'INVENTORY'!$C:$C,\"ADMIN\",'INVENTORY'!$N:$N,1)");
```

Is getting written to the file as

```
COUNTIFS('INVENTORY'!:,1,'INVENTORY'!:,&quot;ADMIN&quot;,'INVENTORY'!:,1)
```

I read on another page somewhere that referencing columns like this wasn't supported either, but I also tried putting them in like "$C2:$C3000" and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue would be that you're using double quotes around your second parameter. PHP is trying to replace $H, $C and $N with actual variables.

Try using single quotes and escaping the existing single quotes within the string.

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) are the docs on how PHP parses double quoted strings which might help.

Comment: Wow, that's a noob mistake.  I didn't read your question clearly at first and even after figuring it out myself I still didn't process what you were saying.  After another visit to the page it hit me.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was to remove or escape the dollar signs ($).  I removed them and it worked fine, and then I escaped them and it also worked!!

Resulting example line:

```
$active_sheet->setCellValue('C3', "=COUNTIFS('INVENTORY'!\$H:\$H,1,'INVENTORY'!\$C:\$C,\"ADMIN\",'INVENTORY'!\$N:\$N,1)");
```

edit: wow, noob mistake.  Credit goes to Ian Belcher.

Answer (score 0):

Column and Row ranges aren't supported by PHPExcel at this point: you need to supply an actual range (e.g. `'INVENTORY'!$H1:$H500` rather than simply `'INVENTORY'!$H:$H`.

There are also a couple of known issues when inserting or deleting new rows or columns into a worksheet when it doesn't correctly adjust an existing formula to reflect that change. Those issues have been fixed in the latest develop branch code on github, so you may want to try again using that.

Comment: I had tried the alternate ranges (mentioned that in my question) and it didn't help.  I just tried the latest development build as well as 1.8 rc1 and both have the same result :(

I even tried moving the insertion of the countifs formulas to the very end of the file based on your comment of the bug and that didn't make any difference either.